# While executing Docker command "docker-compose up" getting error - - "node-app-1 | /bin/sh: [npm,: not found"

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, redis

My docker file

```sh
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app/
CMD ["npm" ,"start"]
```

My docker.yml file

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  redis-server:
    image: 'redis'
  node-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
```

docker-compose output

```
$ docker-compose up
Container visits-node-app-1  Created
Container visits-redis-server-1  Created
Attaching to visits-node-app-1, visits-redis-server-1
visits-redis-server-1  | 1:C 19 Oct 2021 13:10:09.712 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
visits-redis-server-1  | 1:C 19 Oct 2021 13:10:09.712 # Redis version=6.2.6, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
visits-redis-server-1  | 1:C 19 Oct 2021 13:10:09.712 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
visits-redis-server-1  | 1:M 19 Oct 2021 13:10:09.713 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
visits-redis-server-1  | 1:M 19 Oct 2021 13:10:09.715 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
visits-redis-server-1  | 1:M 19 Oct 2021 13:10:09.715 # Server initialized
visits-redis-server-1  | 1:M 19 Oct 2021 13:10:09.715 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
visits-redis-server-1  | 1:M 19 Oct 2021 13:10:09.717 * Loading RDB produced by version 6.2.6
visits-redis-server-1  | 1:M 19 Oct 2021 13:10:09.717 * RDB age 272 seconds
visits-redis-server-1  | 1:M 19 Oct 2021 13:10:09.717 * RDB memory usage when created 0.77 Mb
visits-redis-server-1  | 1:M 19 Oct 2021 13:10:09.717 # Done loading RDB, keys loaded: 0, keys expired: 0.
visits-redis-server-1  | 1:M 19 Oct 2021 13:10:09.717 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
visits-redis-server-1  | 1:M 19 Oct 2021 13:10:09.717 * Ready to accept connections
visits-node-app-1      | /bin/sh: [npm,: not found
visits-node-app-1 exited with code 127
```

Comment: can you show us the docker-compose.yml file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Typically seeing an error around `[npm,` means that you haven't gotten the formatting of the `CMD` correct; it must be a syntactically correct JSON array, or else be a plain shell command.  Can you double-check that you have "normal" double-quotes and spaces in the `CMD` line?

Comment: @s.sacith Dockerfile.yml  version: '3'
services:
  redis-server:
    image: 'redis'
  node-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'